# How do I shuffle without the same card?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to write a program for playing 2 cards game for 2 people. And there is a case that 2 people may draw the same card. Is there a method to eliminate the duplicates?

```
from tkinter import * 
import random

def user1_shuffle():
    random.shuffle(imageList)
    for i in range(0,2):
        labelList[i]["image"] = imageList[i]
def user2_shuffle():
    random.shuffle(imageList)
    for i in range(2,4):
        labelList[i]["image"] = imageList[i]

    
window = Tk() # Create a window
window.title("Two cards game")        
imageList = [] # Store images for cards
for i in range(1, 53):
    imageList.append(PhotoImage(file = str(i) + ".gif"))
    
labelList = [] # A list of four labels
for i in range(4):
    labelList.append(Label(window, image=imageList[i]))
    labelList[i].grid(row=0, column=i)
        
btn1=Button(window, text = "user 1 shuffle", padx = 35, command = user1_shuffle)
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
btn2=Button(window, text = "user 2 shuffle", padx = 35, command = user2_shuffle)
btn2.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)
btn3= Button(window, text = "Quit", padx = 138, 
            command = window.destroy)
btn3.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4)
     
window.mainloop() # Create an event loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't remove the cards from the list when they are drawn? It could solve the duplication problem

Answer (score 1):

You are very close! There is already a shared deck, `imageList`. You just need to make sure that cards are removed from the deck when they are added to a user's hand, and replaced into the deck when a user shuffles a second time (as otherwise you will eventually run out of cards, and your code will throw an exception).